# Как получить доступ к кнопке в SearchView

Tags: java, android, button, searchview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить доступ к этой кнопке? Пытался так `ImageView closeButton = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);` но получал доступ к кнопке очистки поля ввода.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067054/how-can-i-get-back-button-working-when-searchview-in-android
Нашел, подобный вопрос уже задавали, посмотрите

Comment: Решил проблему, спасибо!